# Use of `this` before global variable

Tags: java

I have came accross a concept in java or selenium stating that we use `this` before a global variable. This is done when the global variable and local varibale both have the same name.

This is because if we do not use the `this` keyword then a compile run time error would be generated when we call the variable in a method.

My query is:
Can we not use different name for local and global variable always?
Is there any specific advantage of using same name for local and global variable and then using the `this` keyword.

I am very new to java and selenium so this concept might be very basic.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use different names for local and global variable, and its always a good practice to use local variables than global variables. There is no advantage of using the same name.

Comment: There is no such thing like a "global variable" in Java!

Comment: quite a time ago now, i used to prefix variables with initials from the function name, such as `abc_parent` `bcd_parent` etc. But that didn't make it more readable, on the contrary. If you have functions that handle hierarchy for example and take a `parent` argument, sooner or later you realize it's easier to understand with same name. Scopes are made for this..

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use a different name for every local and global variable.

The reason people use the same name for a local and global variable is usually readability.
If a local variable has the same name as a global variable, someone reading your code will immediately realise the local variable should be assigned to the global variable and thus be the same.

Answer (score 0):

using 'this' in front of a global variable is just for the readability purpose. You can omit using 'this' if you prefer and also you can use different variable names for your global variable and local variable.